# No information about DevExpress controls in automation app

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, automated-tests, ui-automation

i'm writing because I have some hard times trying to get any automation-useful information about DevExpress controls. I do not have ability to see source code of application I'm testing, but UISpy and all other UI verifiers out there don't provide any information, including name, automationID and so on. The only thing that is available is info such as runtimeID, dynamically-assigned automationID and control type. Is there any chance to recognize these controls to get their unique properties? I know it must be some way since Visual Studio does that..

Comment: What the [DevExpress Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/) says about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White is a wrapper for Microsoft's UI Automation Framework. As such, it uses `Condition`s on `AutomationElemement`s' properties in order to find the appropriate element. UISpy is basically a visual reflection of what the UIA 'sees'. There are no other 'low level' properties.

Unfortunately, many developers and control vendors don't pay attention to setting a unique and indicative value for the `AutomationID` or `Name` properties, and thus make it hard to get the element you need.

The best solution I could give you is to create a helper method that works directly with UIA rather than with White, which gives you more flexibility in searching for your control. For example, if you have a DevExpress GridView, you could get all its child elements and query every single one of them for their relative position on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [UI Automation Verify (UIA Verify)](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/). It will help you obtain the automationID.

Comment: It doesn't work either, its basically the same thing as UISpy only with better look. Still the controls don't provide such information as automationID and that's the reason why I'm wondering whow I can get any other piece of information that will help me identify them. This is how it looks like now: [link](http://imageshack.us/f/5/8rv2.jpg/)

Comment: I wonder if this could be control or application specific. For a simple sample I created I can obtain the automationId for the control as shown [here](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=69d41884867ca7c1&id=69D41884867CA7C1!582&sff=1&authkey=!AI3UAxFOKlONBAc)

Comment: It's probably application's implementation fault, but Visual Studio Test somehow does obtain the control with no information provided. The problem is that I need to test it with White and it would be great if there was any way to get any ID of devexpress control... Maybe there is any lower-level possibility than UIAutomation?